# Remove string from HTML for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove a colon at the end of my titles, so I use this:

```js
$('.title').html($('.title').html().replace(':', ''))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title">
  Apples:
</div>
<div class="title">
  Oranges:
</div>
```

It works, it removes the colons, but it also replaces second title `Oranges` with `Apples`?

https://jsfiddle.net/X528L/8/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can give `html` a closure and change each one independently of each other.

```js
$('.title').html(function(index, currentHTML){
  return currentHTML.replace(/:/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title">
Apples:
</div>
<div class="title">
Oranges:
</div>
```

Comment: note that callback second argument also returns existing html

Comment: @charlietfl interesting.  I'm not sure I've ever looked at the arguments for that before.  Then again I hardly ever perform this kind of operation.

Comment: Same concept for `text(function)`, `val(function)` etc

Answer (score 1):

You're close. You're getting a collection because there are more than one element with `title` as class name. I would suggest iterating the element to replace the value.

```
$.each($('.title'), function(key, value) {
    $(value).html($(value).html().replace(':',''));
});
```